# Yii2: PHP Fatal error: Using $this

Tags: php, yii2, apache2

Пытаюсь настроить Yii2 на локальной машине.

Виртуальный хост, для Apache/2.4.16 (Fedora), настроен так:

```
<VirtualHost social_network.loc:80>
    ServerAdmin Yuri@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/social_network.loc/advanced/frontend/views/site
    ServerName social_network:80
    ErrorLog logs/social_network-error_log
    CustomLog logs/social_network-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Ошибка в логах следующая

> [Thu Oct 22 21:40:52.591719 2015] [:error] [pid 12222] [client
>   127.0.0.1:45506] PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in
>   /var/www/social_network.loc/advanced/frontend/views/site/index.php on
>   line 5 [Thu Oct 22 21:41:00.289567 2015] [:error] [pid 12223] [client
>   127.0.0.1:45508] PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in
>   /var/www/social_network.loc/advanced/frontend/views/site/error.php on
>   line 10

Сам index.php

```
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'My Yii Application';
?>
<div class="site-index">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Congratulations!</h1>

        <p class="lead">You have successfully created your Yii-powered application.</p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="http://www.yiiframework.com">Get started with Yii</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="body-content">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
                    fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/">Yii Documentation &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
                    fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/">Yii Forum &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
                    fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/">Yii Extensions &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в настройке локального хоста:

```
<VirtualHost social_network.loc:80>
    ServerAdmin Yuri@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/social_network.loc/advanced/frontend/views/site
    ServerName social_network:80
    ErrorLog logs/social_network-error_log
    CustomLog logs/social_network-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

DocumentRoot должна ссылаться на папку web в директории frontend

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/social_network.loc/advanced/frontend/web
```

Эта директория появляется после инициализации приложения через консоль командой:

```
php /path/to/yii-application/init
```

Comment: И я бы рекомендовал начинать знакомство с yii2 с варианта basic. (Исходя из вопроса легко догадаться, что это именно первое знакомство) - advanced для продвинутых юзеров. Advanced не имеет никаких стартовых преимуществ, напротив, более сложен для понимания.